# Universal Windows Library (UWP) Way to take screenshot?

Tags: c#, screenshot, win-universal-app

I would like to create a ScreenCaptureLib.dll which is intended to be built for Universal Windows.

We already have the following using Windows.Forms:
https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/tree/master/ShareX.ScreenCaptureLib

Obviously none of the Windows Forms code does not work and I would like some pointers in the right direction to get started.

Comment: Please try to follow the official document: [Record the screen with ScreenCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt282147.aspx).

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT thank you! There is a warning however: The ScreenCapture API is only available on mobile devices. Does that mean I cannot use this feature in a Desktop PC?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT thanks for your reply. So basically there is no current way in UWP to do a screenshot or screencast on a Desktop PC, is that right? Are you planning on having this functionality in the future?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no api can be used directly to capture the screen from an UWP app on a desktop for now, but you can try to render the XAML Tree to a bitmap, please refer to [Capturing Snapshot in Windows 8.1 Store App](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2013/10/18/capturing-snapshot-in-windows-8-1-store-app.aspx). You may also submit a request to add this new feature for developing through the Windows Feedback tool. If you find my comments are helpful, can I post them as an answer?

Comment: Hi @GraceFeng-MSFT yes please, thanks for your info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104476/discussion-between-mcored-and-grace-feng-msft).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may follow the official document for [Record the screen with ScreenCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt282147.aspx), but please notice that:

> The [ScreenCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.screencapture.aspx) API is only available on mobile devices.

And for now there is no API can be used directly to capture the screen on a desktop from an UWP app. However, as a workaround method, we can render the XAML tree to a bitmap, to do this, please refer to [Capturing Snapshot in Windows 8.1 Store App](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2013/10/18/capturing-snapshot-in-windows-8-1-store-app.aspx).

You may also submit a request to add this new feature for developing through the Windows Feedback tool.

**Update:**

> The ScreenCapture feature is only supported for mobile devices running Windows Phone 8.1. This API is not supported on Windows 10.