# Changing display colors in UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is there a way to apply canvas effects listed in following MSDN page to all display?

http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/N_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects.htm

So, can the input and output of ,e.g., TemperatureAndTintEffect be the display buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. UWP apps do not have access to the raw graphics card and buffers outside of their app.

Comment: Can you show a reference for that? And, even if you are running service level ?

Answer (score 3):

robertos is correct.  Win2D is a UWP API, and there is no general purpose way for UWP apps to read or write to the display outside of their specific app window.

On mobile devices you can use ScreenCapture APIs to read the displayed image, but there is no way to modify that or replace it with something else.  Or if you want to apply filters only within your own XAML app, you can do that by rendering the XAML visual tree to a bitmap.  More about both options in this thread: [Universal Windows Library (UWP) Way to take screenshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589563/universal-windows-library-uwp-way-to-take-screenshot)